# Tree.com substitute for PowerShell Core running in Linux Docker containers?

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, docker, powershell-core

I am using PowerShell as my shell in developer Docker containers, as I am much more versatile with PowerShell than I am with Bash.

However, I miss having Tree.com from my Windows use of PowerShell that gives me a quick idea of the disk structure.  Tree.com like graphical view of directories would be especially useful for quickly inspecting Docker containers.

What can I add to my Docker containers that would than allow me to run a Tree command? Does not have to be a PowerShell command as long as I can run it from PowerShell.

I would like to at least be able to use it with my PowerShell Alpine base image I use for many projects:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-alpine-3.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can run tree from PowerShell in Linux Docker images just fine. You just need to install it, if not already installed.

If you are using Alpine you can use:

```
apk update
apk add tree
```

Otherwise use:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y tree
```